# How to get a percentage in Mysql query in PHP based on wins/losses columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need this Rank query to also have an IF statement to calculate the wins/losses and put the percentage in a `@percentage` variable. I have no idea how to combine a rank query with a percentage query.

```
mysql_query("SELECT name, wins, losses, level, xp, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM teams p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
WHERE `console` = 3 AND `game` = 23 AND `laddertype` = 1 
ORDER BY xp DESC");
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name, wins, losses, level, xp, wins AS W, losses AS L, TRUNCATE(wins/IF(wins=0,1,wins+losses)*100,0) AS PCT, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM teams p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r WHERE `console` = 3 AND `game` = 23 AND `laddertype` = 1 ORDER BY xp DESC;